# Как можно реализовать платежи между пользователями в Android?

Tags: java, android, платежи

Начал работу над проектом по разделу счетов в кафе и ресторанах.
Концепция такая:
Один пользователь платит за всех, потом они сканируют QR/Штрих код на чеке и в приложении пользователи распределяют кто что ел, программа считает какой человек на какую сумму поел, потом им на аккаунт приходят сообщения, они подтверждают оплату и деньги приходят тому, кто за всех заплатил.

Comment: Делаешь массив или класс из товаров, и в нем у каждого товара делаешь пометку, кто оплатил.

Comment: Это понятно, меня интересует какие библиотеки нужны, для сканера и платежа

Comment: Сканер полно примеров с кодом. А насчёт платежа, это вы к апи с банками